# Paning and orbiting is jittery

Tags: 3d-view

I have used blender for around 4 hours and after around 2 hours paning and orbiting with Scroll wheel and Scroll wheel + LShift became very laggy and jittery. If i try to orbit, it will take often several seconds before the viewport actually starts to move. Also, this problem seems to anly occur in certain modes and in some zoom lengths(?). Any other people having a similar issue and does someone have a fix? I am on Windows 10.

Comment: Actually the problem seems to have fixed itself, but I still wish some other replies, as I fear the problem may resurface.

Comment: Hey there and welcome. Concerning the response of the panning and orbiting, the closer you zoom to an object, the slower it becomes. If you zoomed in too much, it may even seem to not respond at all anymore, while it's just way to slow. To reset that, you can press **Numpad ,**, or look under the **View** menu -> **Frame Selected**.